# how can I add nagios as a service on linux

Tags: linux, nagios

I run the docker nagios from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/jasonrivers/nagios/

Problem is that nagios is not added in `/etc/initi.d/nagios`

Can I add nagios to etc and how?

Thanks ind advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions dealing with Unix/Linux administration belong to https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you think that `/etc/init.d/nagios` should be created (which smell like SysVinit file)? _docker_ and _systemd_ will have different paths and administration logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot run Nagios as service if you are running Nagios as docker container.

You can use `--restart=always` option and run docker like this:

```
$ docker run --restart=always --name nagios4 -p 0.0.0.0:8080:80 jasonrivers/nagios:latest
```

**NOTE:**
Make sure docker service is set to start after reboot!!!

Comment: I want to add nagios service in the docker container to easily restart it